# Android Hello World: Able to install APK into Android, won't run/start APK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project, emulation

I'll make it more concise as possible:

1. I have Eclipse Indigo SR2 with ADT plugin installed.
2. I have checked and confirmed that the ADT plugin is pointing correctly to the Android SDK

installed on my computer. Android SDK version is r16.

1. Followed the instructions on Android SDK Dev site for "Hello World Tutorial", copied/pasted

the code sample provide into my Android project. Nothing wrong here so far.

1. Opened up AVD Manager for Android, created a new AVD running Android 2.3.3. Start up

the emulator and let it run for 1 hour while preparing my dinner (Beef Noodles and a simple

salad).

1. Came back (with a full belly) to find Android emulator running normally. The Android

Launcher app is there to greet me. So, it means the emulator is standing by.

1. Go back to Eclipse (no shutting down any applications in Windows) and start debugging my

Hello World project.

1. Saw the console verbosing the following messages

.

```
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] ------------------------------ 
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] Android Launch! 

[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] adb is running normally.

[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] No Launcher activity found!  
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] The launch will only sync the application package on the 

device!  
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] Performing sync 
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android_Practice'
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] Uploading MarbleRun.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-08 04:57:02 - MarbleRun] Installing MarbleRun.apk... 
[2012-03-08 04:57:05 - MarbleRun] Success!
[2012-03-08 04:57:05 - MarbleRun] \MarbleRun\bin\MarbleRun.apk installed on device 
[2012-03-08 04:57:05 - MarbleRun] Done!
```

1. Noticed the project isn't running in the emulator. There was no "Hello World" text.
2. Thought there may be a problem with loading the emulator, I opened up an old Android

project (less than a year old) and start debugging it. The same emulator debugs the APK just

fine, Buttons, TextViews, RadioButtons, working flawlessly.

1. Noticed that this different project contains new console logs that the first Hello World

project failed to report. The following logs are copied from a different Android project on the

same computer running in the same emulator/debugging environment:

```
[2012-03-08 05:11:26 - Android] Starting activity android.myslocation.MySLocation on device 

emulator-5554  

[2012-03-08 05:11:27 - Android] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { 

act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 

cmp=android.myslocation/.MySLocation }  

[2012-03-08 05:11:27 - Android] Attempting to connect debugger to 'android.myslocation' on 

port 8614
```

1. It is missing from the Hello World project, hence I'm assuming that something is wrong

with my code, and not the emulator.

1. Decided to come to StackOverflow and post my problem so as to figure out what's going

on?

My project code (Currently):

```
package com.marblerun;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Log.d("Test", "Hello World");
            TextView v = new TextView(this);
            v.setText("TESTING THIS OUT.");
            v.bringToFront();
            if (v.requestFocus() == false)
                Log.d("Failed: ", "Nothing works");
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test!", 10);
    }
}
```

Here's my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked if you can start your app from the app drawer? It looks like it is installed but not started.

Comment: App drawer? Nope, it's not in there.  @Marek Sebera, how did you fix the quote markdowns?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I do have an edit privileges, I can repair markup or rephrase any question. How I did that, you can see when you use the `edit` link under question tags

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not used to this sort of editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing something in your [manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), either the whole `activity` tag or the `intent-filter` inside it.

Make sure you have something like this in your AndroidManifest.xml inside of the `application` tag:

```
<activity android:name=".BaseActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```